# How to show my custom lightning web component on any standard object detail page in Salesforce mobile app?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

I want to show my custom lightning web component in Salesforce mobile app.
I have edit the lead detail page and activate it as for desktop and mobile both but that component show only in desktop not on mobile app why?

In this I have added custom lwc(hello lightning component) it shows on dekstop
And this is not shown in app?

[image: First Image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this link,Your form factor must be enable for mobile also

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_form_factors